# about .isotope('reLayout')

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/nSZSg/

```
<div id="container" class="clickable clearfix">

<img class="element"onclick="
  if($(this).hasClass('da'))
  {$(this).animate({'height':'63','width':'182'}).removeClass('da')}
  else
  {$(this).animate({'height':'126','width':'364'}).addClass('da')}
  "style="width:182px;height:63px;" src="http://www.google.com/images/logos/ps_logo2.png"/>

<img class="element"onclick="
 if($(this).hasClass('da'))
 {$(this).css({'height':'53','width':'215'}).removeClass('da')}
 else
 {$(this).css({'height':'106','width':'430'}).addClass('da')}
 "style="width:215px;height:53px;" src="http://static.jquery.com/files/rocker/images/logo_jquery_215x53.gif"/>

<img class="element"onclick="
 if($(this).hasClass('da'))
 {$(this).animate({'height':'63','width':'182'}).removeClass('da')}
 else
 {$(this).animate({'height':'126','width':'364'}).addClass('da')}
 "style="width:182px;height:63px;" src="http://www.google.com/images/logos/ps_logo2.png"/>

</div>
```

---

```
$('.element').live('click', function(){
    $('#container').isotope('reLayout');
});

$('#container').isotope({
    itemSelector: '.element',
    masonry: { columnWidth : 1 }
});
```

i want use .isotope('reLayout') make a image page.
look the GOOGLE logo use "$(this).animate", and JQUERY logo use "$(this).css". try clicking them. the problem is, GOOGLE logo the.animate not work, clicking GOOGLE it opposite, and JQUERY thes.css it correct, how do i fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You are running into a problem I cover in [Isotope - animating item sizes](http://metafizzy.co/blog/isotope-animating-item-sizes/)